# TypeError: Expected Ptr<cv::UMat> for argument '%s'

Tags: python-3.x, opencv

```
lane_image = np.copy(image)
gray = cv2.cvtColor(np.float32(lane_image), cv2.COLOR_RGB2GRAY)


   gray = cv2.cvtColor(np.float32(lane_image), cv2.COLOR_RGB2GRAY)
TypeError: Expected Ptr<cv::UMat> for argument '%s'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UMat это вот [отсюда](https://www.learnopencv.com/opencv-transparent-api/).

В вашем случае `ctvColor` ожидает его как раз получить первым аргументом, поэтому

```
gray = cv2.cvtColor(cv2.UMat(lane_image), cv2.COLOR_RGB2GRAY)
```